# Why was my gravatar removed on meta?

Tags: support, meta, gravatar, profile-picture

I have a confession to make. I am not Jeff Atwood (surprise!). However, I happened to have (and still do, except on meta apparently) his picture as my gravatar just for fun.  It certainly wasn't pornographic in nature, though I'll admit, some might find it offensive. The [gravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534062/n00b) was simply [replaced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162171/n00b) and the email in my profile was appended with the string "+bad_gravatar". What gives? Are there special gravatar rules for meta?

Comment: Other than stealing someone else's photo and uploading it to Gravatar? It could just be that they only noticed the Gravatar here on Meta, and that you pointing out that you use it everywhere will just get it changed everywhere.

Comment: While you have made no claims to be Jeff it could be that here on Meta having his photo *could* still cause confusion and the team don't want casual visitors to think that you *are* Jeff.

Comment: @animuson oh because everybody else's picture is original and of themselves too? I get it. thanks.

Comment: Let's be honest here.  You know exactly why you can't use Jeff Atwood's image.  Why waste everyone's time making a fuss about it?

Answer (score 8):

As you're fortunately self-aware, you're not Jeff Atwood, so please save yourself the embarrassment by not using his picture.

There are no special Gravatar rules for meta; the person who changed your email probably did not notice you were using the same Gravatar email across all sites so neglected to propagate the change across your profiles. So I've done that now.

Comment: Umm, instead of changing his email, why didn't you just upload a new pic and sync that? There's a reason why mods can edit profile pics now :/

Comment: @Manishearth: Lazy to find or make one.

Comment: You are not a unicorn. If there are specific rules against using a picture of someone else it should be explicitly stated. I could have just as easily used a picture of Michael Jackson and nobody would have contested it.

Comment: @n00b It's not so much as who's depicted in your gravatar as much as who is using that gravatar. Jeff Atwood used that gravatar. It's his. You don't get to use it, especially because he's a moderator.

Comment: The top of my head hurts.